# Bootstrap center align two blocks of text vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a small "banner" kind of div which needs to contain 2 parts. On the left I have some h1 text and on the right normal text. The text parts need to be the same height and the text needs to be centered vertical. I have everything like I want except the vertical centered text.

[Code](http://www.bootply.com/XQUQnLHNpF)

```css
@import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css);

#home-wide {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.home-wide-part {
  align-items: stretch;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  background-color: red
}
.text-vertical-center {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="home-wide">
      <div class="col-sm-4 home-wide-part">
        <h1>FIND OUT ABOUT OUR SPECIAL OFFERS</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 home-wide-part">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I just found out my attempt isn't responsive, I need it to be responsive i.e. cols above each other on small screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate solution I could think of is this:

- Move the background color to the parent
- Make the two boxes inline block with vertical align = middle and float = none

  - You also need to eliminate any white space between the two boxes

```css
@import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css);

#home-wide {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}
.home-wide-part {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="home-wide">
      <div class="col-sm-4 home-wide-part">
        <h1>FIND OUT ABOUT OUR SPECIAL OFFERS</h1>
      </div><!--
        white space between inline block occupies
        ~4px and messes up % widths... remove it!
   --><div class="col-sm-8 home-wide-part">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the float none it didnt work, could you explain the function of float:none in this config? for what i understood float:none makes the element not floating. why does it change the hight in this case than?

Comment: i just found out the responsivnes of the cols is gone.

Comment: @SvenB see revised answer. Nearly perfect I guess.

Comment: great answer and i will accept it, for my real problem I need seperate backgrounds though but as i didnt mention it in the question it's only fair to accept the answer.

Comment: Maybe a weard question but how did you find the whitespaces, i can't find them in php storm or other texteditors. When i use phpstorm I usely do every nested div on a new line but when i do it it adds whitespaces?

Comment: (i) The newline *is* a whitespace (ii) apparently the issue with my original answer, that table display makes the design unresponsive, can be fixed by using media queries. If you are still interested: http://www.bootply.com/ILmwx8l6Kf

Answer (score 1):

```
#home-wide{
    height: 100%;
    padding:30px;
    margin-top:50px;
    display: flex;
}

#home-wide{
    height: 100%;
    padding:30px;
    margin-top:50px;
    display: flex;
}

.home-wide-part{
    flex:1 0 auto;  
    color: white;
    background-color:red;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;

}
```

[**Bootply demo**](http://www.bootply.com/Tzk76x6OCY)

Answer (score 0):

I put your text into p tags and added a class

```css
 #home-wide {
   height: 100%;
   padding: 30px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   display: flex;
 }
 .home-wide-part {
   align-items: stretch;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
   background-color: red
 }
 h1,
 p.right {
   height: 80%;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 10%;
 }
 /*  .text-vertical-center{
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
  }*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="home-wide">
        <div class="col-sm-4 home-wide-part">

          <h1><p>FIND OUT ABOUT OUR SPECIAL OFFERS<p></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 home-wide-part">
          <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <p class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore etLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```