# How to find whitespaces and remove them PhpStorm?

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708730/bootstrap-center-align-two-blocks-of-text-vertically) I have a new question. I'm using PhpStorm to  create my php files and my markup looks like this:

```
<div>
     <div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The different spacing is made automatically when pressing enter. But recently I had a new problem (see link above). I had whitespaces which I couldn't delete the only way that worked was not using a new line with a tab like:

```
<div><div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to remove it by selecting the text between the divs like:

[image]

and then pressing enter. The result after: (note: I didn't add a tab its added automatically):

[image]

But why is this code containing whitespaces? I never had problems with it before.

(please view the linked question to see the problem it creates, didn't add it here to make the question more readable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, all whitespace (including tabs, new lines, and regular spaces) is treated the same. If you need to eliminate all spaces, deleted the new line inside the inner `<div>`.

Comment: So the only way to solve this is type all code without any line breaks? This would make readabilty a big issue but if its the only way to i must do that..

Comment: @SvenB If you really need to eliminate all whitespace (without just hiding the div), then yes, you need to remove the line breaks in question. I didn't say remove all line breaks everywhere, just inside the one div where you're having problems.

Comment: oke thanks do you advice to use a pre compiler to remove all whitespaces between divs (not teksts) to make it more readable when writing codes.

Comment: @SvenB No, I don't. It sounds like you only need this in a few places, so I would just eliminate the spacing in those few locations.